# Powershell -noexit needed for my script but how do I kill the powershell instance when done

Tags: session, powershell, scheduled-tasks, wrapper

I am trying to get a rather long Powershell script to run as a scheduled task. The script runs perfectly when I run it from the Powershell ISE but it doesn't work properly if I simply invoke it from a scheduled task unless I specify -noexit. So I have a batch wrapper script which I call using my scheduled task with -noexit specified and that works fine. However, I call this every 20 minutes and so I end up with a very large build up of Powershell session processes. The scheduled task also never ends because of this. Essentially the script checks for the presence of a USB disk with a specific label and if it is present I copy some files to it.

My problem is that because I am using -noexit, the Powershell session keeps running and as I call the script every 20 minutes, they build up. I need a way to kill the Powershell session once my Powershell script has done its thing. I have tried using exit in the last line of my batch file but it doesn't kill the Powershell session.

How can I kill the Powershell session that has been called using -noexit once my Powershell script has completed running?

Another way to possibly solve this is to determine why the Powershell script doesn't run properly without -noexit when called but runs fine when called from Powershell ISE (which is just running the script directly in a powershell session) - which also works fine.

I have looked at using -command instead of -file, I have looked at different wrapper methods. I have tried using new-pssession and remove-pssession.

The script has a number of if else statements in it and what I find is if I run it from a command prompt without the -noexit is the if part runs but the else part is never run - even when the conditions are correct for it to run the else part. Works fine from a powershell session like I said. Very annoying...

This is driving me insane so any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to post your script if you want assistance in determining the issue. Or just kill it as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:`Stop-Process $pid`
or `kill $pid` at the end of your script. It will kill the power shell instance.

Comment: OMG - wish I had of asked sooner. Thanks so much. I see so many other threads where running with -noexit solves the problem but that's not really a solution when you are running as a scheduled task because the task never ends. This answer is absolutely spot on.